# Why bootstrap.js showing the error "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery" when running on localhost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm tested bootstrap for my laravel project in localhost using wamp on windows and when it running it on web browser it shows

> "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery" and "(anonymous function)@bootstrap.min.js:7".

Here I didn't use cdn's for jquery and bootstrap. They are hosted in my local laravel `public` directory?

> Update : added the jquery and bootstrap library initialization

This is the code I've used

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

and

```
</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: that means you don't properly reference jquery on your page

Comment: have you imported jquery.min.js ?

Comment: @Optimuskck I've added them as **<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}">** and **</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>**

Comment: Please show your code that you have includeed for jquery.

Comment: @kaviranga: jQuery has to be **before** Bootstrap.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeh , it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: I'll try as your answer!

Comment: yes and make sure these 2 js files are located in {public/js/}

Answer (score 1):

If you say that your jquery and other files are hosted on your public folder, you should change your src attribute. **{{asset()}}** links to folder: **resources/assets**

You can try:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @AnAntonio Gocaj I'll try this , thanks for sharing your knowledge!